# FLUTTER - Default flutter icon at Recent app in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios, appicon

#### While I open the recent apps tab/screen on iOS I see the default flutter Icon at the top.

[image: Default flutter icon at Recent apps screen]

#### However I have uploaded all the file sizes for both Android and iOS.

[image: All the sizes of appicon]

### Other than the recent app screen all the place is covered by my own AppIcon. How do I fix this?

###### Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can I see your code?  Maybe you didn't even define the icons as the application icon?

Comment: @UrDistraction In that case, the Appicon would also not be found anywhere else. But I only not getting Appicon on the recent apps Screen.

Comment: can you edit the question and add the bit of code where you inserted your definition of the appicon?

Comment: @UrDistraction Sure. I have Added Contents.json file code

Comment: That's not code. iOS has an specific folder with UI in order to check it your icon was setup correctly.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I know this is not code. But I am talking about flutter. In flutter, we just have to change the `Contents.json` file and the actual app icon files to change the app icon.

Comment: Sure, but Flutter doesn't detach you from actual xcode and the Android SDK. There's some libraries that helps you without you having to do it manually, but in many cases you have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened with my app as well. For me, it was a caching issue. Completely uninstalling/reinstalling/clearing cache on the the app worked for me to solve it.